# New Java class doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, eclipse

I just wanted to click on a button to see a text. Do I Need to import the public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)? Or what am I doing wrong? I tried to Import some things, but it didn't help. Java-Code:

```
package com.example.tsd453;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Blume extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public Button btn;
    public TextView tw;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.blume);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnKlick);
        tw = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Text);

        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        tw.setText("Hallo");
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="70sp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnKlick"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post logcat error, and make sure you have `BtnKlick` id and `Text` id on `blume` layout

Comment: post your layout as well as all imports

Comment: Your code seems to be ok..
Have you tried changing the text color and beackground color of the view. Maybe the text color is transparent/ same as background color or something? Also check the visibility of the textview.
And the position of the textview in the layout. Is some other view is being drawn on top of the this text view?

Comment: it didn't help. Might there be a Problem at the beginning, when I created the new JAVA class. I put "java.lang.Object" in the superclass. Is that right? And what is about "public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)", that is in my first Java Class, don't I Need it in the new JacaClass too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

instead of

```
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    tw.setText("Hallo");
```

try this in your onCreate:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            tw.setText("Hallo, Welt!");
        }
    });
```

and you don't need to "implements onClickListener" in class blume

and e.g. use android:layout_below="@id/tw" in the xml file of the button to set the button below the textview

EDIT:

i just tried it on my nexus 5, and this code (i think it is the same like yours) is working

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public Button btn;
    public TextView tw;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnKlick);
        tw = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Text);

        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        tw.setText("Hallo");
    }
}
```

i removed the options menu, but it also worked with it.

screenshot:
https://copy.com/3TX47IAK9gya

screenshot of the code in android studio:
https://copy.com/hbwnH0vZkzMn

Comment: it didn't help. Might there be a Problem at the beginning, when I created the new JAVA class. I put "java.lang.Object" in the superclass. Is that right? And what is about "public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)", that is in my first Java Class, don't I Need it in the new JacaClass too?

Comment: the onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) is used to hold the three dot overflow menu in the upper right of your application - so for the main content it is not needed. you could try to set a fixed text into the xml via android:text="bliblablu" and look where it is located in your layout. this way you can be sure that it is notr covered by the button! give me 10 minutes i'm going to write it myself

Comment: about the super class, i don't know why u use those, and if the button gets displayed, everything is right and should work!

Comment: @user3341325 maybe you could mark it as the solution, or edit your question if you found a solution or the bug, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Button is hiding the TextView, try setting margin like:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
   />
```

and remove center align (at least for one of them).